# Magento 2 Class Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\VariationHandler does not exist

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.2

I am trying to add configurable product in Magento 2 and getting this error

```
Class Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\VariationHandler does not exist {"exception":"[object] (ReflectionException(code: 0): Class Magento\\ConfigurableProduct\\Model\\Product\\VariationHandler does not exist at /home/hqbelectronic/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Reader/ClassReader.php:37, ReflectionException(code: 0): Class Magento\\ConfigurableProduct\\Model\\Product\\VariationHandler does not exist at /home/hqbelectronic/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Reader/ClassReader.php:29, Exception(code: 0): Warning: Narrowing occurred during type inference. Please file a bug report on bugs.php.net in /home/hqbelectronic/public_html/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php on line 444 at /home/hqbelectronic/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/ErrorHandler.php:61)"} []
```

However i have checked `vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/Model/Product/VariationHandler.php` file is there.

I have tried removing `var/generation` `var/cache` `var/page_cache` `var/di`

Also Magento 2 is in developer mode.

Comment: I faced a similar issue and here is the fix. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/204355/magento-2-while-saving-product-from-admin-getting-error-as-class-magento-confi

Comment: @KalyanChakravarthiV thank you for suggessions

Answer (score 1):

You installed BSS Htmlsitemap extension and removed Code from app/code but did not remove database if you want to use this extension just upload a copy of extension into app/code and upgrade and clean cache 
If you don't want to use it remove classes reference from database 
follow these steps 
Login to PHPMYADMIN 
(1) click on database in tables search eav_attributes
(2) Find Classes Raws and delete theme you can search bss_
It will solve your issue !

[image]